# Is it possible to change the button combination for recovery/download mode?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, recovery-mode

I had to press power + home + vol up/down, but my home button just stopped working.
Is there any way to change the key combination?

(I can go into recovery by using the reboot menu, but it would be better if it worked.)

Samsung Galaxy S (I-9000), Android 4.4 (CyanogenMod 11)

Comment: You would need to modify the bootloader in order to change those button combinations. I don't think that's easily possible.

Answer (score -1):

Try holding down the volume up, then camera, then lock button. If this works then use the up/down volume keys to select what you want to do.